XPath: How do I return only one child element, but retain the tree structure?
I'm using this XPath to filter out data.
.selectNodes("(//delete/node|//delete/way)[tag[@k='railway'][@v='station' or @v='platform']]")

It returns this, as expected.
<delete>
    <way id="48016377">
        <nd ref="610578972"/>
        <sys bic="gb"/>
        <tag k="railway" v="platform"/>
    </way>
    <node id="797115753">
        <nd ref="3035237104"/>
        <nd ref="2473620966"/>
        <nm top="left"/>
        <tag k="electrified" v="contact_line"/>
        <tag k="railway" v="station"/>
    </node>
</delete>

How to I amend it so it returns only the tag elements, but retains the tree structure?
<delete>
    <way id="48016377">
        <tag k="railway" v="platform"/>
    </way>
    <node id="797115753">
        <tag k="electrified" v="contact_line"/>
        <tag k="railway" v="station"/>
    </node>
</delete>


xpath has "not" and "except" keywords.

@Kevin As I'm using MSXML, am I not using XPath 1 & 'except' is XPath 2?
The elements I don't want can vary depending on the XML source, so I'm unclear how 'not' will be of use.

Yeah, if they vary it's hard to exclude them specifically.  You can try the ::descendant and name() = 'tag'.  but I am having trouble getting it just right. As you're getting the correct nodes back based on your filter, you may want to just edit the resulting xml and remove the child nodes you don't want to display.

As @Kevin said, hard to do with XPath, much easier to remove the unwanted nodes by code or transform it using XSLT.

selectNodes returns a collection of nodes, but your question sounds as if it returns one delete node. Can you share more of your MSXML code?

SelectNodes returns multiple way & node node, doesn't it?

Yes, but in a list rather than embedded in a <delete>, doesn't it?
